# Mysqldump command not working on command prompt

Tags: mysql

Hello all been trying to create a mysql dump file but not been working. Here is the image.[image]

Can someone please let me know why is this happening?

Comment: you want do backup? `-u root -p prmjfcWSN < aih.sql`

Comment: rename folder name dbms aih to dbms_aih or there is some character for space in command line

Comment: Hey! It is still the same. I have uploaded a new photo. Please check it out. Please if you could help me out. I am in a mess right now.

Comment: Sorry wrong.. `mysqldump -u root -p prmjfcWSN > aih.sql`

Comment: Please be aware that you need to change your root password immediately.  Posting it publicly is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the command you are looking for is `mysqldump` and not `mysql` from the command line.

```
mysqldump -u root -prmjfcWSN > aih.sql
```

More information [in the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html).